# How I can sanitize my input values in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sanitization

I  validated my Node.js inputs so that they won't be empty, but I want to sanitize them too. Please help me how I can do this.

```
req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required!').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('surname', 'Surname is required!').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required!').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required!').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match!').equals(req.body.password);

var errors = req.validationErrors();

if (errors) {
    res.render('user/register', {
        errors: errors,
        user: null,
        title: 'Register'
    });
}
else {
    var userData = {
        name : req.body.name,
        surname : req.body.surname,
        username : req.body.username,
        password : req.body.password,
        avatar : 'No_person.jpg'
    };
    userController.addUser(req,res,userData);
}
```

Comment: You can always use [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com) and their model layer to define validations.

Comment: Maybe you could use: https://github.com/coditorium/nodejs-fluent-validator

Comment: you can use joi framework.

Answer (score 61):

- For most of the framework, you can use [`sanitize`](https://github.com/pocketly/node-sanitize) node module:

  ```
   npm install sanitize --save
  ```

  And then can use like:

  ```
   var sanitizer = require('sanitize')();

   var name = sanitizer.value(req.name, 'string');
   var surname= sanitizer.value(req.surname, 'string');
  ```

  For more can go through [sanitize](https://github.com/pocketly/node-sanitize) documentation
- If you are using `express`, then you can validate and sanitize using [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/) and [express-sanitize-input](https://flaviocopes.com/express-sanitize-input/) packages as follows:

  ```
   const express = require('express');
   const { check } = require('express-validator');
   const app = express();

   app.use(express.json())

   app.post('/form', [
     check('name').isLength({ min: 3 }).trim().escape(),
     check('email').isEmail().normalizeEmail(),
     check('age').isNumeric().trim().escape()
   ], (req, res) => {
     const name  = req.body.name
     const email = req.body.email
     const age   = req.body.age
   })
  ```

  For more can go through [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/) and [express-sanitize-input](https://flaviocopes.com/express-sanitize-input/) documentation.
- If you are using `Hapi`, then you can validate and sanitize using [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi), With the Joi, you can sanitize variable with additional options

  ```
   validate(value, schema, {escapeHtml: true}, [callback])
  ```

  For more can go through [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) documentation.
- If you don't want to use any third party module and want to sanitize using the built-in node. you can try following:

  ```
   // For string variables
   str = typeof(str) === 'string' && str.trim().length > 0 ? str.trim() : '';
   // for boolean values
   bool = typeof(bool) === 'boolean' && bool === true ? true : false;
   // for array values
   arr = typeof(arr) === 'object' && arr instanceof Array ? arr : [];
   // for number values
   num = typeof(num) === 'number' && num % 1 === 0 ? num : 0;
   // for objects
   obj = typeof(obj) === 'object' && !(obj instanceof Array) && obj !== null ? obj : {};
  ```

Comment: @V.Aleksanyan,  Here `string` refers to the value you want to match or the regex expression u want to allow. you can try out this in [`sanitizer runkit`](https://npm.runkit.com/sanitize)

Comment: WHen I submit form I check validation and write your code
var name = sanitizer.value(req.body.name, 'string');
var name = sanitizer.value(req.body.surname, 'string');
var name = sanitizer.value(req.body.username, 'string');
It returns me this error " string is not a valid sanitizer type ". Please say me  Why is it?

Comment: That's just an example to show how it works, It should be like this `var myMatchingString = sanitizer.value(req.mystring, /abc123/);` or a regular expression instead of `abc123`, go through [documentaion](https://github.com/pocketly/node-sanitize), it will explain how to use as a middleware with application

Comment: `check()` isn't built-in with Express. It's part of [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api.html#checkfield-message)

Comment: getting "string is not a valid sanitizer type" for  var name = sanitizer.value(req.name, 'string');

Answer (score 10):

Actually, I wrote a package to solve this problem easily. You can use it or contribute to it on Github.

Download this package from here:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-sanitizer

You can use this utility package to sanitize even foreign languages other than English. Under the hood, regex is used in this library. You can convert your string to URL or filename friendly string. The use cases are given below

```
var string = require("string-sanitizer");

string.sanitize("a.bc@d efg#h"); // abcdefgh
string.sanitize.keepSpace("a.bc@d efg#h"); // abcd efgh
string.sanitize.keepUnicode("a.bc@d efg#hক"); // abcd efghক
string.sanitize.addFullstop("a.bc@d efg#h"); // abcd.efgh
string.sanitize.addUnderscore("a.bc@d efg#h"); // abcd_efgh
string.sanitize.addDash("a.bc@d efg#h"); // abcd-efgh
string.sanitize.removeNumber("@abcd efgh123"); // abcdefgh
string.sanitize.keepNumber("@abcd efgh123"); // abcdefgh123
string.addFullstop("abcd efgh"); // abcd.efgh
string.addUnderscore("@abcd efgh"); // @abcd_efgh
string.addDash("@abcd efgh"); // @abcd-efgh
string.removeSpace("@abcd efgh"); // @abcdefgh
```

[Codeblock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70CbT.png)

[image]

Comment: This library is more akin to a string manipulation library rather than a viable sanitizer. Sanitation should seek to contain the input and preferably be context aware, rather just manipulating a string to some assumed desired result: `string.sanitize("1@2.com")` would ideally not return `"12com"`. Some improvements could include focusing on context specific sanitation (`sanitize.HTMLsafe()`, `sanitize.SQLsafe()`, `sanitize.EmailAddress()`, etc) as well as dropping string helper functions (leave the kitchen sink at home).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Basically, I wrote it to solve a practical problem. Since then many people find it handy and useful. "Sanitizer" means cleaning or disinfecting in our practical life. The word "sanitizer" is used in that practical sense. Nothing more. Besides, the name string-manipulator and string-manipulation both were already taken while publishing this library. 

I will try to add these updates in the future. Thank you, again.

Comment: So far i see this as the best approach to start solving the sanitize problem. i dont want to know what the input is. just like the way js can detect an interger and a string thats how i think it should work and this is somewhat close. The issue is to avoid sql injection by triming unwanted symbols added before or after the input value.

Answer (score 0):

[`validator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) has 5M downloads/week and seems like the most popular package in the industry as of today. `express-validator` uses `validator` as it's core. These are certainly one option, as are other packages like `xss` and `sanitize-html`

There is extensive documentation on both of the validator packages, here is the section on sanitization:

https://express-validator.github.io/docs/sanitization.html

Comment: Link's 404. Copy the relevant content next time, please.

Answer (score 0):

I use Yup for validation. It's a lot smaller package than Joi. I've used Yup on both front and backend and I usually throw my validations into a shared npm package that both the front end and backend projects can have the same validation library

```
npm install -S yup
```

then

```
import * as yup from 'yup';

let schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  age: yup.number().required().positive().integer(),
  email: yup.string().email(),
  website: yup.string().url(),
  createdOn: yup.date().default(function () {
    return new Date();
  }),
});

// check validity
schema
  .isValid({
    name: 'jimmy',
    age: 24,
  })
  .then(function (valid) {
    valid; // => true
  });
```

From Yup's website:

> Yup is a JavaScript schema builder for value parsing and validation.
> Define a schema, transform a value to match, validate the shape of an
> existing value, or both. Yup schema are extremely expressive and allow
> modeling complex, interdependent validations, or value
> transformations.
>
> Yup's API is heavily inspired by Joi, but leaner and built with
> client-side validation as its primary use-case. Yup separates the
> parsing and validating functions into separate steps. cast()
> transforms data while validate checks that the input is the correct
> shape. Each can be performed together (such as HTML form validation)
> or separately (such as deserializing trusted data from APIs).

You will want to create your own validators for special items like password matching etc. This can be done using regex then add the function to Yup like so:

```
let schema = string().matches(/(hi|bye)/);
```

Put all your validation functions into your shared NPM package (including your typescript types etc). The cases where your frontend team is out of sync with validations on the backend will now be less of a concern.

Answer (score -1):

You can create custom middleware that you can integrate into any endpoint (or globally for every request), and it will check if any of the inputs in the request `body` is problematic.

It will check if:

- The input contains some embedded HTML code (scripts of images for example).
- First non-white character is `=`, which make Excel imports vulnerable.

---

**Middleware**

```
const containsHtml = /<[^>]*>/;
const startsWithEqual = /^\s*=/;

const isInvalidInput = (input) => {
  return containsHtml.test(input) || startsWithEqual.test(input);
}

exports.inputValidator = (req,res,next) => {
  let invalid_input_count = 0;
  const obj = req.body;
  const stack = [obj];
  while (stack?.length > 0) {
    const currentObj = stack.pop();
    Object.keys(currentObj).forEach(key => {
      if (typeof currentObj[key] === 'object' && currentObj[key] !== null) {
        stack.push(currentObj[key]);
      } else {
        if (typeof currentObj[key] === 'string' && isInvalidInput(currentObj[key])) {
          invalid_input_count++;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  if(invalid_input_count === 0) {
    return next();
  } else{
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error_code: 'invalid_input'});
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
const express = require('express');
const { inputValidator } = require('./util/input-validator');

...

const app = express();
app.use(inputValidator); // Check every request for vulnerable inputs
```